# How to cast XPathEvalute when it can be XElement or XAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

So I have this code:

```
List<PriceDetail> prices =
                (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants(shop.DescendantXName)
                 select new PriceDetail
                 {
                     Price = GetPrice(item.Element(shop.PriceXPath).Value),
                     GameVersion = GetGameVersion(((IEnumerable)item.XPathEvaluate(shop.TitleXPath)).Cast<XAttribute>().First<XAttribute>().Value, item.Element(shop.PlatformXPath).Value),
                     Shop = shop,
                     Link = item.Element(shop.LinkXPath).Value,
                     InStock = InStock(item.Element(shop.InStockXPath).Value)
                 }).ToList<PriceDetail>();
```

The problem I have is this code:

```
((IEnumerable)item.XPathEvaluate(shop.TitleXPath)).Cast<XAttribute>().First<XAttribute>().Value
```

Sometimes the object from XPathEvaluate could be XElement and then the casting doesn't work. So what I need is a Cast that works with both XAttribute and XElement.

Any suggestion?

Comment: _Sometimes the item could be XElement and then .._ - the `item` in this code can _only_ be XElement. Makes the question hard to follow.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. The object from XPathEvaluate could be from XElement or from XAttribute dependent on the xpath.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Change your XPath expression (`shop.TitleXPath`) from**:

```
  someXPathExpression
```

**to**:

```
  string(someXPathExpression)
```

**Then you can simplify the code to just**:

```
string result = item.XPathEvaluate(shop.TitleXPath) as string;
```

---

**Complete working example**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class TestXPath
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string xml1 =
@"<t>
 <a b='attribute value'/> 
 <c>
   <b>element value</b>
 </c>
 <e b='attribute value'/>
</t>";

        string xml2 =
@"<t>
 <c>
   <b>element value</b>
 </c>
 <e b='attribute value'/>
</t>";

        TextReader sr = new StringReader(xml1);
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr, LoadOptions.None);

        string result1 = xdoc.XPathEvaluate("string(/*/*/@b | /*/*/b)") as string;

        TextReader sr2 = new StringReader(xml2);
        XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(sr2, LoadOptions.None);

        string result2 = xdoc2.XPathEvaluate("string(/*/*/@b | /*/*/b)") as string;

        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);


    }
}
```

When this program is executed, the same XPath expression is applied on two different XML documents and, regardless of the fact that the argument to `string()` is an attribute the first time and is an element on the second, we get the correct results -- written to the Console:

```
attribute value
element value
```

Comment: @Spindel, See the updated answer -- now it contains a full working solution.

Answer (score 10):

Dimitre's solution returns empty string if the element is not found; we can't distinguish it from actual empty value. So I had to make this extension method that handles multiple results by XPath query and returns empty enumeration if nothing is found:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetXPathValues(this XNode node, string xpath)
{
    foreach (XObject xObject in (IEnumerable)node.XPathEvaluate(xpath))
    {
        if (xObject is XElement)
            yield return ((XElement)xObject).Value;
        else if (xObject is XAttribute)
            yield return ((XAttribute)xObject).Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. But there is missing one more else if:
```else if( xObject is XText xText)
                {
                    yield return xText.Value;
                }
```

Answer (score 7):

`XElement` and `XAttribute` are both forms of `XObject`, so if a generic instance of type `XObject` will suffice for your needs, change your Cast`<XAttribute>` to Cast`<XObject>`.

If that won't work for your specific situation, you make use of OfType`<XAttribute>` or OfType`<XElement>` to filter for one or the other, but that would require two passes over the input, one to filter for `XElement` and a second pass to filter for `XAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you make the cast you can check for the type using a code like this:

```
XElement e = item as XElement;
XAttribute a = item as XAttribute;

if(e != null)
   //item is of type XElement
else
  //item is of type XAttribute
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't really understand how I can make it fit into my code. Could you make an example with my code above?